# Action of $Aut(X)$ on $Coh(X)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

I was reading about Bondal and Orlov reconstruction theorem. In particular that for a smooth variety with ample or anti-ample canonical bundle $\mathrm{Aut}(D^b(X)) \cong \mathbb{Z} \times (\mathrm{Pic}(X) \rtimes \mathrm{Aut}(X))$.
This made me wonder whether given an automorphism $f$ of a variety $X$, I can always find a coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ such that $f_* (\mathcal{F}) \ncong \mathcal{F}$.
Is it true? Intuitively it seems true to me, but how to show it? For sure I have to look to something bigger than line bundles, since on projective space line bundles are classified, up to isomorphism, by degree.

Edit: for seeing that no nontrivial automorphism acts nontrivially we can look at skyscraper sheaves of points. Is there we can say in general about vector bundles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is the identity, then of course $f_*(\mathcal F)\cong \mathcal F$.  So you should assume that $f \neq \mathrm{id_X}$.  But then one has that $f(P) \neq P$ for some $P \in X$, in which case you can take $\mathcal F$ to be the skyscraper at $P$.

Comment: Uh, I should have thought to it on my own! Thanks! Can we say anything about vector bundles?

Comment: I haven't really thought about vector bundles.  On $\mathbb P^1$ these are always a sum of line bundles, so at least in that case it doesn't look so good.  I'm not really fluent with the theory of vector bundles on higher dimensional projective spaces, unfortunately.

Comment: Your answer is what I was looking for. The question about vector bundles was more for curiosity sake, whether we can in general find a vector bundle which is moved by the action.

Comment: I think you should ask the vector bundle question as a separate post, since few people are likely to look at the edit to this question (I would guess) now that the question's been answered.